# How to use a stored procedure inside a select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not a developer, so I apologize for the question. I'm a sysadmin with background only in BASH scripting.

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

1) SELECT some columns from a few SQL Server DMV's

2) Add an additional column to the previous output named 'OperState'

3) This 'OperState' column must be the output of a stored procedure for a specific SELECTed column from step 1 (in shell, it would be something like a while read var; do; $OperState =`some command`; echo $var1 $var2 ... $OperState)

The idea is to 1) list all my linked servers with this tsql:

```
SELECT ss.server_id 
          ,ss.name 
          ,'Server ' = Case ss.Server_id 
                            when 0 then 'Current Server' 
                            else 'Remote Server' 
                            end 
          ,ss.product 
          ,ss.provider 
          ,ss.catalog 
          ,'Local Login ' = case sl.uses_self_credential 
                            when 1 then 'Uses Self Credentials' 
                            else ssp.name 
                            end 
           ,'Remote Login Name' = sl.remote_name 
           ,'RPC Out Enabled'    = case ss.is_rpc_out_enabled 
                                   when 1 then 'True' 
                                   else 'False' 
                                   end 
           ,'Data Access Enabled' = case ss.is_data_access_enabled 
                                    when 1 then 'True' 
                                    else 'False' 
                                    end 
           ,ss.modify_date 
      FROM sys.Servers ss 
 LEFT JOIN sys.linked_logins sl 
        ON ss.server_id = sl.server_id 
 LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals ssp 
        ON ssp.principal_id = sl.local_principal_id
```

And add 2) an additional column named 'OperState' where I'll be executing the following other tsql 3) for each 'ss.name' previously selected:

```
 declare @srvr nvarchar(128), @retval int;
 set @srvr = 'my_linked_srvr';
 begin try
    exec @retval = sys.sp_testlinkedserver @srvr;
 end try
 begin catch
    set @retval = sign(@@error);
 end catch;
 if @retval <> 0
  raiserror('Unable to connect to server. This operation will be tried later!', 16, 2 );
```

I know I could use a cursor for the execution loop, but I don't know how to properly reuse the variable from the first select into the loop and also how to produce a new output from this loop into a new column.

Comment: You have to use a cursor in this case (one of the few times where it's justified) because you can't execute stored procedures inside queries (you can do it for functions, but `sp_testlinkedserver` has no functional equivalent). Insert the results of your first query in a temp table or table variable that already has the new column, loop over that, update. This might even be a decent case for an updatable cursor (which, I stress, is a terrible thing to use if you don't have to :-)). Alternatively, build a minimum table with name and state, then do the rest of the query later with a join.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call stored procedures from inside a query.

You'll need a cursor, a temp table, and some fancy error handling, so this is a non-trivial bit of TSQL programming.

Something like this:

```
create or alter procedure TestLinkedServers
as
begin
/*
exec TestLinkedServers
*/

    set nocount on;

    SELECT  ss.server_id 
            ,ss.name 
            ,'Server ' = Case ss.Server_id 
                            when 0 then 'Current Server' 
                            else 'Remote Server' 
                            end 
            ,ss.product 
            ,ss.provider 
            ,ss.catalog 
            ,'Local Login ' = case sl.uses_self_credential 
                            when 1 then 'Uses Self Credentials' 
                            else ssp.name 
                            end 
            ,'Remote Login Name' = sl.remote_name 
            ,'RPC Out Enabled'    = case ss.is_rpc_out_enabled 
                                    when 1 then 'True' 
                                    else 'False' 
                                    end 
            ,'Data Access Enabled' = case ss.is_data_access_enabled 
                                    when 1 then 'True' 
                                    else 'False' 
                                    end 
            ,ss.modify_date
            , cast(null as bit) OperState
            , cast(null as nvarchar(2000)) StateMessage
    into #linkedServers
          FROM sys.Servers ss 
     LEFT JOIN sys.linked_logins sl 
            ON ss.server_id = sl.server_id 
     LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals ssp 
            ON ssp.principal_id = sl.local_principal_id

    declare c cursor local for
    select name from #linkedServers
    for update of OperState, StateMessage

    declare @name sysname
    open c
    fetch next from c into @name
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
         declare @retval int = 1;
         declare @em nvarchar(2000) = null;

         begin try
            exec sys.sp_testlinkedserver @name;
         end try
         begin catch
             set @em = error_message();
             set @retval = 0;
         end catch;

         update #linkedServers set OperState = @retval, StateMessage = @em
         where current of c

         fetch next from c into @name
    end
    close c
    deallocate c

    select * from #linkedServers
end
```